# Can Gears of War 4 be played offline?

Tags: gears-of-war-4

With the release of Gears of War 4, the servers appear to be down.  I would like to play horde mode to kill time, but the game sits there and says "Connecting to Online Services" and after about 30 seconds, it stops trying to connect (no error either).

Can Gears of War 4 be played offline at all?  If it helps, I can play it on Xbox One or PC due to the new Cross Play feature.

Comment: Have you tried it on both PC and XB1?

Comment: Yes - and no luck.

Comment: Hmm. Then I suspect that you are correct when you say that the servers are busy/down. If it doesn't start working within a few days, I'd recommend reaching out to the Microsoft Customer Support.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to Xbox [GoW 4 FAQ](https://support.xbox.com/en-US/games/game-titles/gears-of-war-4-faq#b75e99a6c88b4ef7976871323c7eb929), you need to connect to your Xbox Live account only the **first** time that you start up the game. From the site:

> You’ll need to sign in to the Xbox Live service via the Xbox app when you launch Gears of War 4. Once successfully connected, you can continue to play offline in Campaign Solo mode only. Campaign Co-Op, Multiplayer, and Horde will not be available until you go online.

Comment: No horde though :/.  I've already signed in for the first time as I pre-ordered the Ultimate edition which allowed me to play 4 days early before the official launch today.

Answer (score -3):

NO YOU CANNOT, for PC you are always required to be online in order to play any games.

Comment: Did you really mean to say you can't play any PC games without being online?  Or that you need to be online to play this particular game?  As if you did mean any PC game, well, that's nonsense.

Comment: @MattR - Pretty sure this statement is in the context of Xbox's Cross Play feature